# How to make the scrollbar note scroll when the mouse wheel event happens in C# WINForm datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview, mouseevent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# - how do I prevent mousewheel-scrolling in my combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882993/c-sharp-how-do-i-prevent-mousewheel-scrolling-in-my-combobox)
>   [Disable mouse scroll wheel in combobox VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968189/disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-in-combobox-vb-net)

All
    I have a problem that I want to make the VerticalScrollBar  not scroll in Datagridview when I make the mouse wheeling.

I have get some codes like this:

> ```
>   private void dgwFlowerPics_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
>     {
>         int iRowIndex = iSelectedIndex;
> ```

```
        if (e.Delta > 0) 
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{UP}");  


        }
        else 
        {
            SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}"); 
        }
    }
```

But the scrollBar  still scrolls when I wheel the mouse.How I can resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is similar to [C# - how do I prevent mousewheel-scrolling in my combobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882993/c-sharp-how-do-i-prevent-mousewheel-scrolling-in-my-combobox)

In your event code you can do

```
    void dataGridView1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;
    }
```

after binding the event of course:

```
dataGridView1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(dataGridView1_MouseWheel);
```

Comment: Why WinForms designer does not use this event instead of MouseEventArgs? -_-